# How to solve Excel problem on sum of cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sum

[Add colum E and Colum F values into Colum D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgF33.jpg)
I want to add two cell values as if i delete those values it should not affect the resultant cell and if i change the value or if i add new values in those cells the values should automatically add to the previous resultant cell. E.g cell A1=6 and A2=4 than their sum in cell A3 will be 10. And if i change the values of both cells as A1=8 and A2=5 than A3 should be 23.

I have tried a lot if someone can give me vba code or something else?

Comment: What if after that, someone changes the cells back to 6 and 4, what should the result be?

Comment: than their sum should be added to resultant cell means 10 add to the resultant cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address <> [A1].Address And Target.Address <> [A2].Address Then Exit Sub
  If IsEmpty(Target) Or Not IsNumeric(Target) Then Exit Sub
  [A3] = [A3] + Target.Value
End Sub
```

This picture should help, I guess.
[image]
Use the latest code, please.

If you need to sum 3 cells, e. g. `A4 = A1 + A2 + A3`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address <> [A1].Address And Target.Address <> [A2].Address _ 
    And Target.Address <> [A3].Address Then Exit Sub
  If IsEmpty(Target) Or Not IsNumeric(Target) Then Exit Sub
  [A4] = [A4] + Target.Value
End Sub
```

If you need to have 2 triplets of cells, e. g. `A3 = A1 + A2` and `B3 = B1 + B2`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row > 2 Then Exit Sub
  If IsEmpty(Target) Or Not IsNumeric(Target) Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Column = 1 Then
    [A3] = [A3] + Target.Value
  ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then
    [B3] = [B3] + Target.Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: not working bro kindly help me i am not expert in vba or could you please make a video

Comment: Thanks this code is working properly what should i do if i want to apply the same code to another colum or row than this is not working

Comment: You can edit the code as you need. In the code, you can see two cells, A1 and A2, under control and cell A3 is the target. You can change any of them. If you need more cell triplets on the same worksheet, the code should be improved.

Comment: Bro thanks this code work only for two cells means i want to add new cell ranges but not working how can i do this i am adding a pic of my sheet

Comment: kindly make code for 3 cell tan i will cange myself

Comment: i have lined image of my work

Comment: Added the code to sum 3 cells.

Comment: Added the code for 2 triplets of cells.

Comment: Thank you so much @rotabor you help me. May you live happy